# How to write a sql query that groups rows and then do some calculation on one of the column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was asked this question in an interview. The table given was

```
| dept | reward |
| ---- | ------ |
| A    | 2500   |
| B    | 4000   |
| C    | 4500   |
| A    | 4000   |
| C    | 3500   |
| A    | 3500   |
| B    | 3000   |
| A    | 500    |
| C    | 2500   |
```

I needed to write an SQL query that lists the name of depts which have reward > 10,000. The answer here would be dept A(2500+4000+3500+500=10500) and C(4500+3500+2500=10500).
I wasn't able to answer it. Can somebody guide me with this? Any help will be appreciated.

I apologise in advance for weird framing of the question.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but this is a very basic `group by` question.  It seems odd that someone would interview for a job where SQL is listed as a skill and not be aware of such a fundamental part of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select dept, sum(reward)
from t
group by dept
having sum(reward) > 10000
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. There was some ambiguity in it before.

Comment: I noticed. See new query.